# Integer to Binary Conversion

Tags: python, binary, integer

I'm calculating the conversion from an integer to a binary number wrong. I entered the integer 6 and got back the binary number 0. which is definitely wrong. Can you guys help out? I'm using python 3 by the way.

```
def ConvertNtoBinary(n):

    binaryStr = ''
    if n < 0:
        print('Value is a negative integer')

    if n == 0:
        print('Binary value of 0 is 0')
    else:
        if n > 0:
            binaryStr = str(n % 2) + binaryStr
            n = n > 1
    return binaryStr

def main():
    n = int(input('Enter a positive integer please: '))
    binaryNumber = ConvertNtoBinary(n)
    print('n converted to a binary number is: ',binaryNumber)

main()
```

Comment: I'm assuming you're doing this either as homework or for your own enjoyment/exercise, which is great.  If you just want something that works, use the built-in function `bin()`.  (You may need to strip off the leading `0b` from the result, depending on your purposes.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is:

```
n = n > 1
```

This does the boolean comparison "is n greater than 1?". What you likely want is n >> 1, which bitshifts n.

EDIT: Also, you're only doing this process once - I imagine you'll want to do it on some condition, like

```
while n > 0:
```

EDIT2: The comment form John Machin is correct, and I fixed the above to reflect that.

Comment: I think i got it.  Is 6 converted to binary, 110?

Comment: indeed it is: (2^0)*0 + (2^1)*1 + (2^2)*1 = 2 + 4 = 6

Comment: You mean `n >> 1` ... `n >> 2` divides by 4

Answer (score 0):

What about the build-in function "bin"?

```
>>> bin(4711)
'0b1001001100111'
```

Batteries included!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you are doing, but the Python function for doing this is `bin()`. If you want to convert *to* binary, you can do `bin(numbertoconvert)`. If you want to convert *from* binary, you can do `int(numbertoconvert, 2)`. `int()` takes an optional argument of what base it uses. To get a regular binary number from `bin()`, you can do `int(bin(numbertoconvert)[2:])`

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that `if n>0`, should be a while loop, not an if statement.